# Syntax Error in response xml using jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, jsonp

I am executing the following Ajax code for my Sample Mobile Application.I get a response Xml with syntax error which I can see it on firebug console.

```
 script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   function receive(result){
        console.log(result)
     }

 $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#home", function( event ) {

    $("#submit").bind("tap",function(){
         var FromCurrency = $("#fromcurrency option:selected").val();
         console.log(FromCurrency)
         var ToCurrency = $("#tocurrency option:selected").val();
         console.log(ToCurrency)



         $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            type:"GET",
            contentType: "content/xml; charset=utf-8",
            async:false,
            url: "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate",
            data: {FromCurrency :FromCurrency,ToCurrency :ToCurrency},
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            jsonpCallback: "receive",
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Success")
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseType)
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>
```

Response Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">61.155</double>
```

Error Screenshot:
 http://s28.postimg.org/f11gvkgyl/Error.jpg

Please help me to find what's my mistake.I am stuck here for more than three days.Thanks!

Comment: yes because `jsonp !== xml` jsonp gets only json not xml and you cannot do a cross domain request with dataType xml.

Comment: checked with `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` the same error exists.